# My resume was snatched by someone

Tags: linkedin

What things should i do because my resume was snatched by someone.

Would I report this urgent? Because I'm afraid that that scammers will use my resume to convinced other people.

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean 'snached'?

Comment: If by "snached" you mean "copied" than inform your HR (or if you are out of or freelancing) HR departments that someone is impersonating one of their employees.

Comment: You've tagged this as LinkedIn. Do they have any procedures for reporting fraudulent profiles? Or at the very least, someone to whom you can say "this person's resume is exactly the same as mine..."?

Comment: "would I report this urgent?" - What do you mean by this?

Comment: Maybe they want to hire you?

Answer (score 8):

I don't believe this is your problem. A resume is just a reflection of your past work and education. Or, it should be. Anyone can put anything in their resume, so it doesn't really matter if they lie and make up stuff, or they use your resume, to apply to jobs.

It's also not an identification document so I have no idea who can be scammed with just a resume? If I put Jane Masters at the top of my resume, it's not like I can get a bank card in that name or something.

edit - ah LinkedIn? If your whole profile was copied, I would report that to LinkedIn and probably they will remove it.

Answer (score 2):

No one can use your CV to convince people...

A CV/Resume is yours. If people could use other CV's to convince people, everyone would be in their dream jobs. That's why companies have tests and interviews to see if people are lying or not.

The only risk you have is if you have your personal details and address on your resume and someone may know where you live but even then this is not a major problem.

You don't have a problem here, just continue doing what you're doing. If they've copied the format then that's not a problem, if they've copied the entire content then they will be caught out eventually anyway.